# wirte a csv file from C script called multiple times

Tags: c, csv

I am trying to make a script which writes data in two columns of a csv file (2 variables), I use fopen and fprintf but I see that the file gets back to 0 kB in each iteration:

```
for (j=0;j<iterations;j++){
File *fp;
fp=fopen("file.csv", "w");
fprintf(fp, "%f %f \n", var1[j], var2[j]);}
```

what is the issue?

Comment: First mistake, you don't check `fp != NULL`, suppose you don't have write permissions in the current directory.

Comment: as @iharob says: Check the return value of `fopen` and possibly also `errno` if on *nix.

Comment: If you want to call the "script" several times and add to the file, you should use the append flag `"a"` as second parameter to `fopen`. Or, miuch better, call `fopen` (and `fclose`) ouside the loop.

Comment: the append "a" will keep the previous writings and continue to write in the csv file?

Comment: Yes, but don't do that in this case; see my answer below.

Comment: "C script" ? C is one of the languages that doesn't even resemble scripting ..

Comment: I change it but the file just remains to 1kB with one single writing only

Comment: @electr0n: I had mentioned the append mode (`"a"`) because I thought you wanted to run the same program various time., That was before you had posted your loop. Please forget about opening the file (without closing it, i.e. possibly without committing the changes to disk!) various times. Your notion of file access is wrongheaded and first thing you know is that you have run out of valid file handles. Look at my answer below, which shows how to write data to a text file.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea of how to use a file is misguided: You don't have to open the file for every transaction on it. Open the file once, check whether that succeded, do your writing or reading and then close the file.

What you want to do is more along these lines:

```
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen("file.csv", "w");

if (fp)  {
    for (j = 0; j < iterations; j++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%f %f\n", var1[j], var2[j]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: this did not work neither it writes 1kB and then stops

Comment: I get a message that there is a conflict between FILE * and char *

Comment: It is very tedious to help you because your reports are so fuzzy. "It writes 1kB then stops" - Does that mean that you get correct output, but fewer lines than you expected? "I get a message" - Is this message a compiler message? If so, what code are you using? Did you mix up `fprintf` (with an `f`) and `printf` or `sprintf`? Please, be more analytical. Programming isn't about trying out a lot of things and looking what works.

Comment: I mean that I use fprintf and it writes only one pair of values for var1 and var2 despite the multiple iterations executed

Comment: But you are not using the code I proposed in my answer?

Comment: Very likely not. I've tested this code and it compiles and prints all value pairs.

Comment: Let's stop it. I've given you an example of how to write the contents of an array to a file and I'm loth to guide you by the hand based on unreliable information. The code above works. If you still have a problem, it is elsewhere. (Is `iterations`greater than 1? Are the arrays big enough to hold `iterations` values?)